sanitize-html converts special character such as '&' to '&amp'
How do I handle this type of situation? I have a nodejs application with nextjs frontend. Users want to use character such as '&'. However I realized that after sanitizing it with this package sanitizeHtml before storing in my database. I realized that it changes character such as "&" to '&amp'.
This is for user input. Characters coming from rich text editor are rendered well.
I wanted to prevent users from ever using "&" but I realized that they can simply copy and paste the content.
So, how do I handle this?
Here is my code:
const sanitizeText = (text)=>{
 const clean = sanitizeHtml(text, {
  allowedTags: [],
  allowedAttributes: {},
  allowedIframeHostnames: [],
  allowedSchemes: [],
});

return clean;
 }

is there a way I can make the character '&' to be saved as '&' in my database instead of the '&amp'? Or is there an efficient way to completely prevent users from using such character

&amp; is the HTML entity for the ampersand character - I would guess the package you’re using is doing this to avoid a situation where the & by itself is unintentionally used in conjunction with another string to represent another HTML entity altogether, considering the latter is a reserved character in HTML (more info). What specifically is the issue with storing it this way? It’s not clear what the problem is for your specific use case.

Is this the package?

Input should be sanitized when it comes out of the database, not when it goes in there.

It’s incorrect to sanitize things as HTML unless you intend to render them as HTML, like in the case of rich text – at which point &amp; is correct. For a typical plain text field, all you should do is escape the text as HTML on output, which most template engines do automatically. See also XY problem

@Ry, thank you very much. I think this solves my problem. I was sanitizing the regular input. I wasn't having problem with the rich text. It was data such as user name, first name, etc. Due to my limited experience, I didn't know if I needed to sanitize that or not.  While I know that react handles that automatically, I was considering the fact that someone may query my api directly outside react, etc.

@Guy Incognito, this is quite confusing because I read that it is important to sanitize user inputs before storing them in the database.

@esqew here is the issue, if user have a blog title this way: Visit UK & the US and publish it. My current solution sanitizes the blog title before storing in my database. With the current package that I am using which I used not to allow any tag, it simply converts '&' to "&amp". This way, the blog title becomes "Visit UK & the US" when I display it because it was stored this way in my database after sanitization with the option not allow any tag

Sanitizing at insert is incorrect. There is no danger in storing unsanitized data in a database, as long as it gets sanitized on output. And if someone queries the API directly then it's not your problem if they don't sanitize what they're getting from it for whatever they use it for (which might not even be HTML output.)

Yeah, it’s important to consider the various places that data can be used, so good work on recognizing that. Generally, the responsibility for providing correct data in a particular format lies with the part that introduces that format, so e.g. if you have a JSON API that someone then uses to create HTML, it’s your responsibility to ensure that data is correctly escaped as JSON and it’s their responsibility to ensure that data is correctly escaped as HTML. (And good modern tools for HTML or JSON output – like React, as you mentioned – will do these things automatically.)

@Guy Incognito, thank you for this explanation. So, on get request, I should sanitize the response before sending to client for all input?

@Ry, thank you very much. I will focus on validation for regular plain texts and sanitization for rich texts.

If you're specifically sending HTML content then yes sanitize before sending, if sending the data only then no, it's the client's responsibility to sanitize it.
